# Execute An SQL Query from JSP

Tags: sql, jsp, jdbc

I have an sql query : `select name || 'hh' from table;`

How can I use the same statement in JDBC?

```
String sql = "SELECT username || 'hh' from dba_users";   -----> not working
PreparedStatement stmt  = conn.prepareStatement (sql);
```

Comment: Do you know how to execute a statement using JDBC?  It's no different, you just need the right set of imports.

Comment: It worked. Closing the Question.....

Comment: Next time you ask a question like this, at least include an explanation of what you mean with 'not working': does it result in an error (if so what error), or if it does something unexpected: describe your expectation and the actual result.